# How do i solve RouterProvider TypeError in react-router-v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My Code -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "../App.css"
import About from "./About"
import App from "../App";
import {
  createBrowserRouter  ,
  RouterProvider
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element:<App/>,
    },
    {
      path:"/about",
      element:<About/>,
    }
  ])
  
  
  
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    
    <RouterProvider route = {router}/>
   
  
  )
```

Error -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
at RouterProvider

When i was not using routes the app was working as intended but after using routes nothing is getting rendered on the page .
Please help me solve this error ?

Comment: You've a typo in your code, the [`RouterProvider`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider) takes a `router` prop, not `route`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <RouterProvider router={router} />
```

Attention the attribute has changed to `router`